# Tkinter update progressbar from imported code

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am creating a gui application using Tkinter, which imports other pieces of code stored in external .py files which contain time consuming functions. What I want to do is have a progressbar on my gui window which gets updated according to some function running in my imported script.

Gui script example:

```
#gui script
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from somefile import somefunc

progcomp = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=200, mode = 'determinate', maximum=100)
somefunc()
```

External function example:

```
#somefile.py
def somefunc():
    for i in range(1000):
        #dosomething
        #update progressbar of gui script
```

My actual code is too long to show in a question like this, so I chose to represent it as simply as possible. My question is, is this possible or will I have to change the infrastructure to accomplish?

Comment: better `def somefunc(progress_bar):`

Comment: long-running `for` loop will be problem because it will stop `mainloop()` so window will freeze.

Comment: @furas I tried that already but it seems that the bar only updates when somefunc() returns.

Comment: because your functions stops `mainloop()` which gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, redraws widgets,, execute functions when you click button, execute function assigned with `after()`, etc. When `somefunc` returns then it returns to `mainloop()` and it can redraw widgets. But inside your function you can use `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to update widgets once.

Answer (score 2):

You could use threading to implement this. Below is a very rough example of this.

**threaded_task.py**

```
import threading
import time

class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, progress):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.progress = progress
    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.progress.step(1)  # Update progress bar
            time.sleep(1)  # Simulate long running process
```

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from threaded_task import ThreadedTask

root = Tk()
progcomp = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=200, mode = 'determinate', maximum=100)
progcomp.grid()

task = ThreadedTask(progcomp)
task.start()

root.mainloop()
```